# change transition between screens in kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, screen, kivymd

I made a button in kivymd to transition between screens, but I want to change its current transition to fade, please how do I do this?? (thanks alot in advance for your help)
this is the current button code:

```
    MDTextButton:
            text: '< Back'
            padding_x: 0
            custom_color: (244/255, 246/255, 214/255, 1)
            pos_hint: {"center_y": .1}
            root_button_anim: True
            on_press:
                # change direction to to non-movable
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
                root.manager.current = 'Screen1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your `on_press`:

```
root.manager.transition = FadeTransition()
```

see the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager.transition).